# HTTPClient StringEntity PUT troubles

Tags: java, json, http, apache-commons

I am struggling with creating a plain text file on a server via HTTP PUT. I am using apache commons httpClient. My credentials are working but there is no body content in my request. What must I do to create the file like this? It works as intended when I try via hurl.it (ie setting my credentials, and setting a body). What I would like is the string "hej" to show in the file body. After getting this to work I intend to use a JSONString. The following code generates an empty file on the server (204 response):

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String encoding = http_username + ":" + http_password;
        encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String(encoding.getBytes());
        HttpPut httpput = new HttpPut(http_path);

        HttpEntity content=null;
        try{
         content = new StringEntity("hej");
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            logger.error("Failed to Encode result");
        }


        logger.info("executing request " + httpput.getRequestLine());
        try {
            httpput.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            //httpput.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpput.setEntity(content);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpput);
            Header[] allHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
            for (Header h : allHeaders) {
                logger.info(h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I have tried both setting a content type and not doing it, no difference. What basic thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your current code doesn't send a file at all, it sends some plain text in the request body. What is your server side resource expecting (it would help us help you if you included the resource method).

Comment: The server side is not accessible to me so cant provide much info on it. you can list the contents here: http://upload.cmstest01.ku.dk/ the data.json file is produced by the code above, while the data2.json is produced when I try via hurl.it

Comment: Can't give you advice without knowing what a valid request is supposed to look like. But what you can do is, run your hurl.it test with Google Chrome Developer Tools open, and inspect in the Network Tab, all the HTTP properties that are sent to the server. Then duplicate those settings in your client code. If you need help then post the property information you find to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Base64.encodeBase64String appends a newline character at the end of the string, which throws everything off!

```
String encoding = http_username + ":" + http_password;
encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String(encoding.getBytes());
encoding= encoding.replace("\r\n", ""); //This fixes everything
```

Wow, that just took me a couple of days to figure out!